# ¿Cómo hacer esta consulta en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta que me trae los *cursos* a los que se encuentra inscrito un *estudiante*, una vista donde se cuentan los *temas totales* que pertenecen a los *cursos* y los *temas* que fueron vistos ya por el *estudiante*. Dentro de la misma consulta realizo el porcentaje de avance dividiendo los temas que ya vio entre los totales por 100 y muestro el resultado.

```
  SELECT avance.curso_id, cursos.curso_nombre, usuarios1.nombre, usuarios1.ap_p, avance.usuario_id, vtemastotal.total_temas, 
COUNT(*) as temas_vistos, ( COUNT(*) / vtemastotal.total_temas*100 ) porcentaje
FROM avance 
INNER JOIN cursos ON cursos.curso_id = avance.curso_id 
INNER JOIN usuarios1 ON usuarios1.id = avance.usuario_id 
JOIN vtemastotal on vtemastotal.curso_id=cursos.curso_id 
GROUP BY avance.usuario_id, avance.curso_id,vtemastotal.total_temas
```

Y este es el resultado de la consulta:

```
usuario_id  nombre            ap_p    curso_id  curso_nombre    total_temas temas_vistos    porcentaje  
2          Estudiante          A_P       4        Test               7           4           57.1429
2          Estudiante          A_P       5        Excel              2           2           100.0000
3          Estudiante No. 2    AP        4        Test               7           6           85.7143
5          Estudiante No. 3     XV       4        Test               7           7           100.0000
7          Estudiante No. 5     ES       6        Word               1           1           100.0000
```

¿Es posible evitar que se repita el nombre del *estudiante* pero se mantengan todas las filas? Algo así estoy buscando:

```
    nombre           curso         porcentaje
    Estudiante 1     Test            50
                     Excel           100
    Estudiante 2     Word            100
                     Excel           67
                     Test            30
    Estudiante 3     Excel           90
                     Word            80
```

Comment: Ya intentaste agregar DISTINCT despues del select?

Comment: No. No es posible. Una base de datos muestra datos en todas las filas porque esa es la idea. Lo que vos buscas, es un tema de la vista donde vas a mostrar los datos. Si es lo que queres, quien se tiene que encargar de eso es la vista.

Comment: Sí, pero literal no cambia la consulta @AlexisNarvaez

Comment: Ya te contesto un moderador así que estas resulto.

Comment: Vale gracias, investigaré al respecto @gbianchi

Comment: Hola Enrique, me temo que eso no es posible debido a que el motor asocia resultados con valores. Muchos motores proveen herramientas para formatear la salida, en el caso de ocracle se utiliza SQL PLUS, te recomiendo ver esta guia https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a82950/ch4.htm en el ejemplo Example 4-9 Suppressing Duplicate Values in a Break Column. Tambien puedes ver esto https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-remove-duplicates-without-distinct/. Espero te ayude! Happy coding!

Comment: A ver.. estrictamente hablando, poder se puede, solo deberías numerar las filas por cada grupo de un mismo estudiante y en caso que la fila = 1 retornas el nombre y sino un blanco. Ahora bien, no es una buena práctica hacer este tipo de cosas, las bases de datos, solo deberían entregarnos los datos, como se representan estos datos, debiera ser responsabilidad de la aplicación o de la capa de "Vista".

Comment: Esto lo deberías delegar en quien consulte esta información o la procese para mostrarla.